# Can you build AMP on xhtml?

Tags: html, xhtml, amp-html

My company uses .xhtml file format for the front-end, but we're being pushed to add AMP to our static pages. In my research, I haven't found anything that says you can use the .xhtml format, and when I try to deploy a site with an AMP .xhtml page, I get this error: "Error Parsing /storeAmp.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 1] The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed."
I'm using the boilerplate code which works perfectly fine in my local environment, so I know it's not the code. I'm not sure what could be causing this issue and haven't been able to find anything in on the AMP project website.

Note: I've tried using a .xhtml and .html to build the page, but neither work in the test environment. When I use .html it still calls a .xhtml page that does not exist.

Am I missing something? Is there a way or is this a hopeless endeavor?

Here's the boilerplate code I'm trying.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html amp>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="This is the AMP Boilerplate.">
    <link rel="preload" as="script" href="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js">
    <link rel="preconnect dns-prefetch" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/" crossorigin>
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <!-- Import other AMP Extensions here -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <style amp-custom>
    /* Add your styles here */
    </style>
    <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>

    <link rel="canonical" href="testsite.html">
    <title>My AMP Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want to change that boilerplate to be valid XHTML, you should run it through the W3C validator; it will tell you what's wrong with it. Casing errors, missing namespace, no slashes, missing values to attributes etc.

Comment: The W3C validator doesn't check for AMP compatibility. Every time "amp" is included in a tag, it's considered an error, which is incorrect. I'm trying to figure out if AMP is even a possibility with xhtml or if it's a lost cause.

Comment: Since any sort of xmlns attribute on the html element fails AMP validation, I'd say it was a lost cause.